# Receive broadcast message on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, broadcast

First - sorry for my English, I'm not "native writer".

I'm sending broadcast message in C++, and want to receive it on Android device. I created such code:

```
    System.out.println("receiveBroadcast()");
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(3866);
    socket.setBroadcast(true);
    System.out.println("Listen on " + socket.getLocalAddress() + " from " + socket.getInetAddress() + " port " + socket.getBroadcast());
    byte[] buf = new byte[512];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for data");
      socket.receive(packet);
      System.out.println(packet.getAddress());
      System.out.println("Data received");
    }
```

It works when I compile it as standard java SE console application and run on other computer connected to the network.
It doesn't work on Android and I have no idea why. On Android it just waits for data but never receives it:

```
03-18 15:47:05.045: I/System.out(16651): receiveBroadcast()
03-18 15:47:05.055: I/System.out(16651): Listen on /:: from null port true
03-18 15:47:05.065: I/System.out(16651): Waiting for data
```

What is interesting, when I run it as standard Java console Application under Windows system, instead of "Listen on /:: from null port true" I get "Listen on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 from null port true".

I have in manifest such permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```

Please, help!

Comment: See this - http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP. If you make it work, you can answer your own question for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for link. I wrote it in detail but unfortunately there is no advice solving my problem. I tried this Java code on yet another PC that uses wireless communication and it works there too. For sure the problem is in Android, but still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you implement the getBroadcastAddress method from the link? I think your problem is obtaining the address to bind. Remember that Android phohes typically have at least two interfaces - WiFi and mobile.

Comment: As I saw in the example, getBroadcastAddress is used for sending only. I need to implement receiving only and there method getBroadcastAddress isn't called at all. Anyway, I tried to call this method and it fails on my device.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. But the method is declared in the previous paragraph in the article, so probably that's why it doesn't work :)

Comment: I mean - I copied whole method with body. It compiles, but crashes my application when called.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I thought I share this here as in the future it may help others.

the famous code written [here](http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP) didn't work for me neither the 2 solution I am suggesting as it depends on the your device and os

anyway you may guys want to try some of these solutions:

1-
create a lock on your wifi so it wouldn't be turned off after some time of inactivity

```
WifiManager wifi;
wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiManager.MulticastLock mLock = wifi.createMulticastLock("lock");
mLock.acquire();
```

2- check this link [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/OpbSdp9FTmA) as in some cases broadcast messages are blocked by the OS